# Avoiding unwanted spaces in a shortquote / inline quote environment

Tags: environments, quoting

In a book project, I use the following simple definition of a `shortquote` environment, mainly to make the use of inline quotations a bit more flexible than just using ``quote'' (source)

```
% inline quotations
\newenvironment{shortquote}{``}{''}
```

When I use it, e.g., in

```
He said of his bar chart: 
\begin{shortquote}
This Chart is different from the others in principle, as it does
not comprehend any portion of time, and it is much inferior in utility to those that do; for though it gives the extent of the different branches of trade, it does not compare the same branch of commerce with itself at different periods.
\end{shortquote}
(\emph{Atlas}, 1st edition, 1786, p. 101)
```

I get the following, that leaves an extra space before and after the quote.
There is probably a better way to do this.  Any suggestions are welcome.

From so other related queries, perhaps I need `\ignorespaces` somewhere, but I don't see how or where.

[image]

Comment: if you don't want to complicate the macros to remove the space you could just not add the space in your document. you have space just as `\`\` foo ''` has space but `\`\`foo''` does not.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that the newline following `\begin{shortquote}` counts as a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define the environment to always ignore spaces at the beginning and end:

```
\newenvironment{shortquote}{``\ignorespaces}{\unskip''}
```

this will ignore *spaces*, but it won't ignore blank lines, so be sure to enter
your quote as you show it in your question.

Comment: I think it's better to guard the unskip, as in my answer, as otherwise a blank line before the end of env has different effects on the main vertical list (weird low level error) or in a parbox (removes vertical rather than horizontal) space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- reasonable warning.  (i did say not to leave blank lines and use the command exactly as the op showed in the question.)

Comment: yes but if you test for that it's the same as the answer I gave but less safe (just as long as OP is aware of that:-)

Comment: In my uses of this, as I always do with environments, perhaps out of bad habits, I use `\begin{}` and `\end{}` on separate lines.  One reason for this is I might want to change a `shortquote`into a `quote` environment later.

Comment: @user101089 -- that's actually a very good practice, and it should work with the suggested code as long as you don't leave blank lines.

Answer (score 2):

The spaces are not related to the environment definition, they are added in your document, however you could redefine the environment to remove them if you don't want to avoid adding them when marking up the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{shortquote}{``}{''}
\newenvironment{xshortquote}{``\ignorespaces}
    {\ifvmode\PackageError{shortquote}{dont leave a blank line}{}\else\unskip\fi''}

\begin{document}

\begin{shortquote}xx\end{shortquote}


\begin{shortquote} xx \end{shortquote}

\begin{xshortquote}xx\end{xshortquote}


\begin{xshortquote} xx \end{xshortquote}

\end{document}
```